# How do I use the multiprocessing module in Python to call different copies of an application?

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have an application that takes an input file, does some computation and creates an output file with the results. In order to execute batch runs, I created a Python module that will create the input file, run the application then parses the output file to save the results I need to a CSV. Each run only takes about 1-2 seconds but when I’m trying to perform a large number of runs, this takes quite a bit of time since the Python script runs sequentially.

What I’d like to do is utilize the multiprocessing module in Python to call multiple instances of the script I created to speed up the process. How I’ll need to do this is by creating a copy of the application into another directory such that I have two versions of the application in two separate directories. From there, I would call the applications from my Python script using the multiprocessing module so I can have two runs going at the same time.

I’m assuming I’ll need to use `queue.Queue` in the multiprocessing module, but what I can’t figure out is how I can basically define the two copies of the application, and alternate between the two as long as it’s not currently in use. Unfortunately, my code is on a different system so I can’t copy it to here but it’s basically doing something like this within a class I created:

```
my_first_list = [12, 13, 14, 15]
my_second_list = [21, 22, 23, 24]
my_third_list = [34, 35, 36, 37]

for val1 in my_first_list:
  for val2 in my_second_list:
    for val3 in my_third_list:
      execute_my_script(val1, val2, val3)
```

The `execute_my_script` method creates an input file, calls the application and parses the output file. What I’d like to do is for each iteration of the loop, call `execute_my_script` but alternate between the two copies of the application (which are in different directories) that would run as separate processes such that I can have them running in parallel (i.e. multi processing). In other words:

- First iteration of the loop runs copy 1 of the application.
- Second iteration of the loop runs copy 2 of the application.
- Third iteration of the loop runs copy 1 of the application.
- Fourth iteration of the loop runs copy 2 of the application.
- And so on...

Any tips or pointers on how I might go about accomplishing this? Thanks!

Update: The application I'm calling is a standalone exe. It's basically a directory with the exe and a separate input file. When you run the exe, it uses the parameters in the input file to perform the calculations then creates another output file.

Comment: Is your "application" a Python function or module that is accessible from the batch script? Or is it a standalone executable program?

Comment: I believe you can achieve your goal with the help of a Load Balancer. You can use Nginx as a load balancer and then distribute your traffic to multiple instances of your application.

Comment: There's no need to create multiple copies of the application. Have a single copy of the application, and call it multiple times in parallel with different parameters Doesn't have to be 2 - it can be 4, 8, or 100.

Comment: See the answer below - does that help? @shred

Comment: @AndreasT The application I'm calling is a standalone exe. It's basically a directory with the exe and a separate input file. When you run the exe, it uses the parameters in the input file to perform the calculations then creates another output file.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a piece of code that runs the same piece of python code as both parent and child, with a pool of 5 sub-processes. For this to work, the file should be named `mp_so.py`.

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Pool

import sys
import subprocess
import time 

def run_child(arg_tuple):
    print(arg_tuple)
    subprocess.call(["python3", "mp_so.py", "child", arg_tuple[0], arg_tuple[1]])

def main():
    if sys.argv[1] == "main":
        print("this is the main")
        inputs = [f"intput_{x}" for x in range(10)]
        outputs = [f"output_{x}" for x in range(10, 20)]
        with Pool(5) as p:
            p.map(run_child, zip(inputs, outputs))

    else: 
        input = sys.argv[2]
        output = sys.argv[3]
        print(f"child process - input is {input}, output is {output}")
        time.sleep(1)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```